# Uncaught Reference Error - one function works the other doesn't

Tags: javascript

I've read a lot about uncaught reference errors here and think I have the idea down - when the script is trying to call a function or reference a variable that hasn't been initialized yet.  However, I am uncertain how to fix this, and why in my case one function works and the other doesn't.

I have one JS file with two functions in it, and one HTML file with a form.  The form calls function1 onSubmit, and that works fine.  A radio button inside of the form calls function2 onClick, and that's when I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleGender is not defined onclick @ forms.html:20
```

Why would my first function work and not the second?  It seems to me like they are operating under the same premise.

```js
function calculatePFT()
{
  var userForm = document.getElementById('userValues');
  var pullups = userForm.userPullups.value;
  var crunches = userForm.userCrunches.value;
  var runMinutes = userForm.userMinutes.value;
  var runSeconds = userForm.userSeconds.value;
  
  var runScore = 0;
  
  if(runMinutes < 18) { runScore = 100; }
  else
  {
    var minDiff = runMinutes - 18;
    var minPoints = minDiff * 6;
    var secPoints = Math.ceil(runSeconds/10);
    
    runScore = 100 - (minPoints + secPoints);
  }
  
  var score = parseInt(pullups*5) + parseInt(crunches) + parseInt(runScore);
  
  document.getElementById('scoreBox').innerHTML = "You scored " + pullups + " pullups and " + crunches + " crunches and a run time of " + runMinutes + " minutes " + runSeconds + " seconds.  TOTAL SCORE: " + score;
}

function toggleGender(var gender)
{
  alert("Inside");
  var maleForm = document.getElementById('male');
  var femaleForm = document.getElementById('female');
  
  if(gender == "f")
  {
    alert("Female");
    maleForm.style.display = 'none';
    femaleForm.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Male");
    maleForm.style.display = 'block';
    femaleForm.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Javascript Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<section id="wrapper">

<h3>PFT Calculator</h3>

<form action="#" id="userValues" method="post" onSubmit="calculatePFT()">

  <div id="gender">
    <span class="maleFemale">Male <input type="radio" name="maleFemale" value="male" CHECKED onClick="toggleGender('m')" /></span>
    <span class="maleFemale">Female <input type="radio" name="maleFemale" value="female" onClick="toggleGender('f')" /></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="male">
    <div class="scoreLine">
      <div class="label">Pullups:</div>
      <div class="entry"><input type="number" name="userPullups" min="0" max="20" default="18" class="scoreEntry" required /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="female">
    <div class="scoreLine">
      <div class="label">Hang:</div>
      <div class="entry"><input type="number" name="userHang" min="0" max="150" default="70" class="scoreEntry" required /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="scoreLine">
    <div class="label">Crunches:</div>
    <div class="entry"><input type="number" name ="userCrunches" min="0" max="100" default="100" class="scoreEntry" required /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scoreLine">
    <div class="label">Run (Minutes):</div>
    <div class="entry"><input type="number" name="userMinutes" min="0" max="100" default="19" class="scoreEntry" required /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scoreLine">
    <div class="label">Run (Seconds):</div>
    <div class="entry"><input type="number" name="userSeconds" min="0" max="59" default="30" class="scoreEntry" required /></div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" value="Calculate Score!" id="submitButton" /></div>
  
</form>

<span id="scoreBox"></span>

</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It really helps if you don't define your HTML and JS in *completely separate code snippets so they aren't connected*.

Comment: Also, look at your browser's Developer Tools Console, you have at least one obvious syntax error that should be highlighted there.

Comment: I'm seeing an error concerning the line for adding scores through parseInt, working on fixing that now.

Comment: Also, to clarify for future use - you're saying that I should post my HTML and JS file in the same code snippet block?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> function toggleGender(var gender)
> ```

You have a syntax error here. Argument names should not be prefixed by `var`. This causes the functional declaration to fail (hence why you get a reference error when you try to call it).

```js
function calculatePFT()
{
  var userForm = document.getElementById('userValues');
  var pullups = userForm.userPullups.value;
  var crunches = userForm.userCrunches.value;
  var runMinutes = userForm.userMinutes.value;
  var runSeconds = userForm.userSeconds.value;
  
  var runScore = 0;
  
  if(runMinutes < 18) { runScore = 100; }
  else
  {
    var minDiff = runMinutes - 18;
    var minPoints = minDiff * 6;
    var secPoints = Math.ceil(runSeconds/10);
    
    runScore = 100 - (minPoints + secPoints);
  }
  
  var score = parseInt(pullups*5) + parseInt(crunches) + parseInt(runScore);
  
  document.getElementById('scoreBox').innerHTML = "You scored " + pullups + " pullups and " + crunches + " crunches and a run time of " + runMinutes + " minutes " + runSeconds + " seconds.  TOTAL SCORE: " + score;
}

function toggleGender(gender)
{
  alert("Inside");
  var maleForm = document.getElementById('male');
  var femaleForm = document.getElementById('female');
  
  if(gender == "f")
  {
    alert("Female");
    maleForm.style.display = 'none';
    femaleForm.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Male");
    maleForm.style.display = 'block';
    femaleForm.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Javascript Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<section id="wrapper">

<h3>PFT Calculator</h3>

<form action="#" id="userValues" method="post" onSubmit="calculatePFT()">

  <div id="gender">
    <span class="maleFemale">Male <input type="radio" name="maleFemale" value="male" CHECKED onClick="toggleGender('m')" /></span>
    <span class="maleFemale">Female <input type="radio" name="maleFemale" value="female" onClick="toggleGender('f')" /></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="male">
    <div class="scoreLine">
      <div class="label">Pullups:</div>
      <div class="entry"><input type="number" name="userPullups" min="0" max="20" default="18" class="scoreEntry" required /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="female">
    <div class="scoreLine">
      <div class="label">Hang:</div>
      <div class="entry"><input type="number" name="userHang" min="0" max="150" default="70" class="scoreEntry" required /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="scoreLine">
    <div class="label">Crunches:</div>
    <div class="entry"><input type="number" name ="userCrunches" min="0" max="100" default="100" class="scoreEntry" required /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scoreLine">
    <div class="label">Run (Minutes):</div>
    <div class="entry"><input type="number" name="userMinutes" min="0" max="100" default="19" class="scoreEntry" required /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scoreLine">
    <div class="label">Run (Seconds):</div>
    <div class="entry"><input type="number" name="userSeconds" min="0" max="59" default="30" class="scoreEntry" required /></div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" value="Calculate Score!" id="submitButton" /></div>
  
</form>

<span id="scoreBox"></span>

</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice - however, I removed the "var" and reloaded the page, and still get the same error as before.

Comment: @Nicholas — I've added a live demo. The only thing I changed was removing the var. It works now.

Comment: Thanks!  I turned on "Show invisible characters" and something appeared at line 21 that wasn't seen before...had to compare your adjusted file with my original file line by line until I thought to show invisible characters.  Appreciate your help.